# Copy Block of XML and Paste it in Same Document

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to figure out a way to copy a block of XML and then paste that below another block.  For example, I want to copy everything within Cars and paste it below the Truck nodes.

Source:

```
<Vehicles>
  <Cars>
    <Car name="Mustang">
      <engine>V8</engine>
    </Car>
    <Car name="Taurus">
      <engine>V6</engine>
    </Car>
  </Cars>
  <Truck name="F-150" />
  <Truck name="Ranger" />
</Vehicles>
```

Desired result:

```
<Vehicles>
  <Truck name="F-150" />
  <Truck name="Ranger" />
  <Cars>
    <Car name="Mustang">
      <engine>V8</engine>
    </Car>
    <Car name="Taurus">
      <engine>V6</engine>
    </Car>
  </Cars>
</Vehicles>
```

I have tried methods such as AddAfterSelf and CloneNode but they copy and paste at the same time.  I need it to copy the Cars block, and then after running other code, paste it after the last Truck node.  I have also tried using Clipboard but can't figure out how to copy a block of XML and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold a reference to the root node of what you want to copy and then call CloneNode as often as you want, whenever you want.

**EDIT**: This makes me feel very dirty:

```
doc
    .Element("Vehicles")
    .ReplaceAll
    (
        doc
            .Element("Vehicles")
            .Elements("Truck")
            .OrderBy(i => i.Attribute("name").Value)
            .Union
            (
                new []
                {
                    new XElement
                    (
                        "Cars", 
                        doc
                            .Element("Vehicles")
                            .Element("Cars")
                            .Elements()
                            .OrderBy(i => i.Attribute("name").Value).ToArray()
                    )
                }
            )   
    );
```

But it does the job.

Comment: Maybe I need to explain my situation a little more.  I am sorting the Truck nodes by Attribute("name") using ReplaceNodes.  When I do that, it deletes Cars and everything within it because of how this document is structured.  I need to be able to copy Cars, run the code to sort Truck by name, then paste Cars.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. However, I have to ask - if you already have the whole XML document in memory, is it really so bad to just create a whole new document into which you'll output the data in the order you want? If yes, then you're probably going to have a problem even just using XmlDocument.

Comment: I was trying to prevent creating a new document because I have another program that is reading these XML files (there are many files I'm building this tool for) by file name.  Maybe there's just a problem with my code to sort the XML.

Comment: Here is my code to sort the XML:
XElement file = XElement.Load(@"..\Test.xml");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\Test.xml");
file.Element("Cars").ReplaceNodes(file.Element("Cars").Elements("Car").OrderBy(m => (string)m.Attribute("name")));
file.Save(@"..\Test.xml");
doc.Element("Vehicles").ReplaceNodes(doc.Element("Vehicles").Elements("Truck").OrderBy(n => (string)n.Attribute("name")));
doc.Save(@"..\Test.xml");

Line 5 deletes Cars and everything in it.

Comment: Well, if the files aren't too big, you could use LINQ to SQL. Load the whole file into XDocument, and then do `doc.Element("Vehicles").ReplaceAll(doc.Element("Vehicles").Elements().OrderBy(i => i.Name == "Truck" ? 1 : 2))`. Feel free to ask questions if you don't understand what that does.

Comment: That at least doesn't delete Cars anymore but it doesn't sort anything.  I need to sort by Attribute("name").

Comment: Getting closer. I did 'doc.Element("Vehicles").ReplaceAll(doc.Element("Vehicles").Elements().OrderBy(i => i.Name == "Truck" ? 1 : 2).OrderBy(m => (string)m.Attribute("name")))' but it's ignoring my sort and save of Cars.

Comment: You have to use ThenBy instead of OrderBy for any successive ordering. Don't ask me why :)

Comment: Either way works.  But it's still ignoring my sorting/saving of my Cars code.  It seems like the Truck code is reading the file before the file is saved from the Cars code, even though the Cars code is run before the Truck code.  If I flip-flop the code, the vice versa happens.

Comment: I just figured it out too.  A different way than your answer.  Not sure which way is best.  Posting my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load XML file to sort cars.
XElement file = XElement.Load(@"..\Test.xml");

//Sort cars by "name" and save the file.
file.Element("Cars").ReplaceNodes(file.Element("Cars").Elements("Car")
    .OrderBy(n => (string)n.Attribute("name")));
file.Save(@"..\Test.xml");

//Load XML file to sort Trucks.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\Test.xml");

//Sort trucks by "name" and save file.
doc.Element("Vehicles").ReplaceAll(doc.Element("Vehicles").Elements()
    .OrderBy(t => t.Name == "Truck").ThenBy(m => (string)m.Attribute("name")));
doc.Save(@"..\Test.xml");

//Open sorted XML file to verify sort.
Process.Start(@"..\Test.xml");
```